# File not uploading to ftps server using vbs code

Tags: vbscript

I am using below code to upload file to an ftps server.
If I upload the file through command line using below code it works file.

But when I use it in vbs the file is not getting uploaded
The code is given below

```
WshShell.Run "c:\program files (x86)\winscp\winscp.com /command ""option batch abort"" ""option confirm off"" ""open ftps://USERNAME:PASSWORD@FTPSITE.COM:PORTNUMBER/"" ""put C:\MyFolder\ForSFTP\TestFile.txt /savefile/"" ""exit""", 1, True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need quotes around the executable path:

```
WshShell.Run """c:\program files (x86)\winscp\winscp.com"" /command ""option batch abort"" ""option confirm off"" ""open ftps://USERNAME:PASSWORD@FTPSITE.COM:PORTNUMBER/"" ""put C:\MyFolder\ForSFTP\TestFile.txt /savefile/"" ""exit""", 1, True
```